# Angular build : An unhandled exception occurred: The service is no longer running

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to build my angular project, but I always get this fatal error :

An unhandled exception occurred: The service is no longer running

The log error contain :

```
[error] HookWebpackError: The service is no longer running
   at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:48:9)
   at C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3060:12
   at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:115:1)
-- inner error --
Error: The service is no longer running
   at C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:822:29
   at sendRequest (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:697:14)
   at start (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:820:9)
   at Object.transform2 [as transform] (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:879:5)
   at C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2157:55
   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
   at Object.transform (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2157:14)
   at EsbuildExecutor.transform [as esbuildTransform] (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1980:62)
   at EsbuildExecutor.transform (C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\esbuild-executor.js:113:21)
   at async C:\Users\w_h20\OneDrive\Bureau\Raboto\ApplicationDevis\SPA Client\Devis\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\css-optimizer-plugin.js:70:53
```

I tried many times to uninstall and to downgrade the version of my NodeJs & my Anular CLI, but unfotunately without results.

ng serve is working, but ng build doesn't.

I'm using :

NodeJS : ***16.16.0***
Angular CLI : ***15.1.16***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple NodeJs versions...I resolved this with downgrading my NodeJs version and also my Angular CLI version.

***NodeJS : 16.16.0  ==> 14.19.0***

***Angular CLI : 15.1.16 ==> 12.2.16***